# Left Join returns more records

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with related data.
one table is for products. and the other price. In price table one product may appear several times. 
How can I return the result showing the products without containing duplicate rows

My Query is

```
select             p.Product, sum(p.Qty), max(pr.netprice)
from               Products  p
  left outer join  Price pr
  on               p.Product=pr.Product
where              p.brand=''
group by           p.Product,pr.Product
```

but return more rows as right table have multiple records

please help

Comment: What is wrong with your current query? Remove second field (,pr.Product) from group clause, will result become better?

Comment: Give some sample data, that would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think distinct is the way to go, I think group by should result in what you want if done correctly. Also, I don't think you need to group on values from both tables.. You should really understand what you want to. Give us example data and it will be easier to answer your question. Try this:

```
select p.Product, sum(p.Qty), max(pr.netprice)
from Products p
left outer join Price pr on p.Product = pr.Product
where p.brand = ''
group by p.Product -- only group on param.
```

Comment: Good answer.  I think it's important to highlight that by removing pr.Product from the group by, you removed the grouping on the secondary table.  That will eliminate the duplicate rows from the original query.

Comment: On a second thought I think the first solution should work also since the join in joining on Product and grouping on Product. However, he doesn't needs to group on columns that is not used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distinct keyword.  That will remove duplicates.  ALthough, if there are different prices for a given product, there will be one record per unique price per product if you remove the Max().

```
select DISTINCT p.Product, sum(p.Qty),max(pr.netprice)
from Products p 
left outer join Price pr on p.Product=pr.Product 
where p.brand='' group by p.Product,pr.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting distinct in select. I am not sure it will work, but try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum then use Tomas answer above. This will give you a unique product list with the total quantity and maximum price for each product

```
select p.Product, sum(p.Qty), max(pr.netprice) 
from Products p 
left outer join Price pr on p.Product = pr.Product 
where p.brand = '' 
group by p.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

What about changing it this way:

```
SELECT p.Product, sum(p.Qty), 
       (SELECT max(pr.netprice) 
          FROM Price pr 
         WHERE p.Product=pr.Product
       )
  FROM  Products  p
 WHERE  p.brand=''
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

SELECT p.Product, p.Qty, MAX(pr.netprice)
FROM Products p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Price pr ON p.Product=pr.Product 
WHERE p.brand='' 
GROUP BY p.Product, p.Qty

Comment: In the question he wants to sum the quantity, so you can't group on that.

Comment: But is that what you really want? Of course you don't get duplicates, but you also don't get the sum of the quantity as you have in your own sample code.

Comment: yes, You are right i have not got the duplicates but the Qty is not sum .. How can i get that

Comment: SELECT distinct p.Product, p.Qty, MAX(pr.netprice) FROM Products p LEFT OUTER JOIN Price pr ON p.Product=pr.Product WHERE p.brand='' GROUP BY p.Product, p.Qty  (but still not grouping by product)

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? You should also give us sample data, that would make it easier to test by our self.

Comment: Product table Product A B C A A QTY 1 2 1 3 4 Price table Product A B C A A A  Price
4
5
2
3
6
1
please help